Last viewed tags section gone from left navigation?
I'm pretty sure this question has not been asked yet and I'm a bit tired of repeatedly searching for tags in the search bar. I remember that a few weeks ago, there was a section on the left navigation bar that said something similar to "last viewed tags" which would show the last tags for the questions you viewed. But now it is no longer there?
And to be clear, no, I am not talking about the Tags button. That just shows a list of all tags and has not disappeared.


It was an experiment, so kinda not surprising for it to go away at some point.

As @KevinB said, it seems it was part of an experiment related to tags. It doesn't seem to be in effect currently.

This is likely correct, though I don't think we've heard anything specific about it being shut off.

You could follow the tags that you are interested in and they will ahow up on the right side.
